# Why is QML ScrollView not available in QtQuick.Controls 2.0?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have the following QML, and am trying to add the ScrollView around the ListView:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 // Works if 1.4 is specified
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    property alias textOutput_listView: textOutput_listView
    property alias doOffsetGainCal_button: doOffsetGainCal_button

    Button {
        id: doOffsetGainCal_button
        x: 40
        y: 38
        text: "Do Offset/Gain Cal"
    }

    ScrollView {
        ListView {
            id: textOutput_listView
            x: 40
            y: 99
            width: 300
            height: 256

            model: textOutputListModel
            delegate:  Rectangle {
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: 100
                height:18
                Text { text: modelData }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle2
                color: "#ffffffff"
                visible: true
                z: 1
                anchors.fill: parent
                border.color: "#7d7d7d"
                opacity: 0.2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I import QtQuick.Controls 2.0, the ScrollView is reported as 'not a type'. If I import 1.4 it works.

Googling has not indicated that ScrollView has been deprecated or replaced.

Am I wrong in my expectation that versions of QML components replace older ones - meaning am I supposed to import 2.0 and 1.4?

Comment: Googling was wrong: see [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html#modularity-and-simplicity). The main point in introducing new controls is to provide LIGHTWEIGHT controls. Have a look to the linked page for a brief presentation of the difference between the two modules.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo - Thanks. That page contains both 'Scrollview' and 'replaced', yet isn't in the first five pages of Google results for those two terms. Which seems odd to me.

Comment: @SteveFallows I'm just guessing, but it could be because it's fairly new? Or perhaps qt.io is doing something wrong.. I dunno. I use Google to check reference pages often, and a lot of the time even stuff that's been there for a while isn't at the top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

[`ScrollView`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html) has been introduced in Qt Quick Controls 2.2 in [Qt 5.9](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.9_Release). It provides flicking and non-interactive scroll indicators on touch, and switches to interactive scroll bars and disables flicking when interacted with a mouse pointer.